# Laravel 3, Eloquent: SELECT with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-3

I ***know*** this is going to be a simple one, and I've looked ... I must just be missing it.
It's been a while since I've coded in Laravel (or, at all for that matter :), and I can really use a nudge in the right direction.
FYI, this is for a REST-ish web service, so there's really no UI.

**GOAL:**
Process Find requests against the `people` table where the request can be for one field, or five fields, or anywhere in between.
Here are the `$accessible` fields:

- fname
- mi
- lname
- aka
- gender

**EXAMPLE REQUESTS:**

- `$input = array('aka'=>'sammy','gender'=>'female')`
- `$input = array('fname'=>'william','aka'=>'will')`
- `$input = array('fname'=>'william','lname'=>'smith')`
- `$input = array('lname'=>'smith')`
- etc., etc., etc...

**TRIED:**
A)

```
$payload = new PersonEntity( (array)$input );
```

B)

```
$model = new PersonEntity( (array)$input );  
$payload = $model->get();
```

C)

```
$model = new PersonEntity;

foreach( $input AS $field => $value )
{
    if( in_array($field, $model::$accessible))
    {
        $model->where( $field, '=', $value );
    }
}

$results = $model->get();
```

**EXPECTING:**
I am expecting the return of an array of objects which match the request.

**RECIEVING:**
Depending on what I'm trying at the moment, when I do get results, the entire table is returned.
Via the profiler, I'm able to see that it's simply running `SELECT * FROM people`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I did understand but with Laravel you can chain where conditions in this way:

```
$model = DB::table('people');

$model = $model->where(function($model)
{
    foreach( $input AS $field => $value )
    {
        if( in_array($field, $model::$accessible))
        {
            $model->where( $field, '=', $value );
        }
    }
});

$results = $model->get();
```

Comment: Oooohhhhh, that's right!!! The callback function ...  I _knew_ I'd done it before. Thanks-a-bunch for jogging my memory!